# Setting up a session_store with subdomains interfere with Twitter login. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, omniauth, sorcery

In the development environment. Twitter API requires us to login from 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost or any other hostname.

However, we are also testing our local app via sub domains. In `session_store.rb`:

```
Foobar::Application.config.session_store :redis_store, :servers => REDISTOGO_URL, :key_prefix => "foobar:rails:session", :expire_in => 1.week, :domain => '.localhost.dev'
```

Every time we try to log in onto Twitter, we get `401 Unauthorized`. If we set `:domain => '0.0.0.0'`, I can log on to Twitter fine. Having:

```
Foobar::Application.config.session_store :redis_store, :servers => REDISTOGO_URL, :key_prefix => "foobar:rails:session", :expire_in => 1.week
```

Without the `:domain =>` part, I can log onto Twitter without any problems.

Why would setting up a `:domain` in `session_store.rb` interfere with Twitter log-ins?

Answer (score 0):

The `:domain` option on the session store set's the domain the session id cookie will be issued for. The browser will only send the cookie back to the application when the cookie's domain setting and the current url's hostname match.

Having `:domain => '.localhost.dev'` in your settings like in your example means that you'll have to access your site using `http://localhost.dev` or and subdomain of it (`http://www.localhost.dev`) would be fine, too. You won't have any success when accessing your application via `http://0.0.0.0` because of the not matching hostname.